# My polymer project is not up to date

Tags: caching, polymer, rendering, service-worker

I have been working on a polymer web app which I started in polymer 1.0
My problem is though i push new code some times the web app is in old version only. To solve the problem i disabled service worker(To avoid caching) and added time stamps to my back end APIs. Still I am facing the same problem.Suggest me solution.Also some times some elements don't respond and render.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try clearing the cache.

Comment: I want permanent solution. customers don't know what is cache and how to clear it.

Comment: Is it possible to post your content of `polymer.json` file?

Comment: Polymer.json file is missing in my project. what if it misses?

Comment: What about `bower.json`?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/04f17fb3d55a90754b0146a9adaeac55    is my bower.json

Comment: How do you build your app without polymer.json? You said this is for customer.

Comment: I am building with gulp. Does adding Polymer.json solve my problem?

Comment: Using `polymer build` is recommended that needs `polymer.json` file. Can you post the code for gulp build?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Hareesh-kumar-kuruba/e164daf9d83e8d877c017db3f3a0edd4 this is my gulpfile.js    , I want to know root cause

Comment: Is the issue fixed?

Comment: I did not remove the precache gulp task as it caches only static resources, but I enabled service-worker. Issue solved to some extent, not fully.

Answer (score 0):

When you push new versions of your code, it doesn't automatically update the cached versions of those resources in the users' browsers. And I believe your service worker is coded to serve the cached resources, thus making your new versions of your code not served.

In order to serve the new versions, you need to make the service worker update its cached resources. This can be done by making the service worker cache the resources again (thus caching the new versions this time).

This can be done by making changes in your service worker file (even a single character change will do!). Once the users' browsers sees that the service worker has changed, it will download the updated service worker, run its install phase (thus caching the new versions of your resources).

If you can't decide what "change" to do in your service worker file, simply changing the cache name will do. Make sure to do this everytime you push new versions of your resources.